# How to make a filter query with values of a queryset using Q objects and & operator?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

could you support me with the following question?

I have this models:

```
class Tarifa(models.Model):
    limite_i = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    limite_s = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class Calculator(models.Model):
    tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    base = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    limite = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a first queryset that brings the information of a row of my calculator model:

```
qsl1 = Calculator.objects.values_list('base')
```

This queryset returns all the amounts that I have in base:

```
<QuerySet [(Decimal('3000.00'),), (Decimal('5000.00'),), (Decimal('1000.00'),)]>
```

Later, I enter this query as a subquery in the following queryset:

```
qsl2 = Tarifa.objects.filter(
Q(limite_s__gte=qsl1) 
& Q(limite_i_isr__lte=qsl1))
.values_list('limite_i')
```

This second query values ​​that my 'limit_s'> = 'base' and 'limit_i' <= 'base' and then bring me the value of 'limit_i'

Now the problem is that I only return the comparison of the first value that is 3000.00, I also need to make the comparison of 5000.00 and 1000.00 and all the other values ​​that are added.

But I do not know how you could support me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to call values_list with the attribute flat when you need only one field.

```
bases = Calculator.objects.values_list('base', flat=True)
```

This will return a flattened version of the queryset:

```
<QuerySet [Decimal('3000.00'), Decimal('5000.00'), Decimal('1000.00')]>
```

After fetching bases you should make a Q object with or queries like below:

```
import operator
from itertools import reduce

query_args = []
for base in bases:
    query_args.append(
        Q(limite_s__gte=base) & Q(limite_i__lte=base)
    )

query = reduce(operator.or_, query_args)

tarifas = Tarifa.objects.filter(query).values_list('limite_i', flat=True)
```

Comment: thank you I will test your suggestion and tell you what happened

Comment: I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given) - line 2 is :  Q(limite_s__gte=base), Q(limite_i__lte=base)
    )

Comment: I'm sorry, I think it's ok now, I forgot a &

Comment: total thanks if it worked, now my question is already the Queryset returns to me <QuerySet [Decimal ('133.22'), Decimal ('2765.43'), Decimal ('22377.75')]> and returns the values ​​from lowest to highest , how can I retrieve the values ​​so that they are saved in my Calculator model within the limit according to the value that is valued from the base.

Comment: Hey @AlfredoGodinez, welcome to SO! Did this answer worked for you? If yes then click the checkmark to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your `ForeignKey` field with [**`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)  like this:

```
class Calculator(models.Model):
    tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='calculators')
    base = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    limite = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you can try like this:

```
Tarifa.objects.filter(Q(limite_s__gte=F('calculators__base'))&Q(limite_i__lte=F('calculators__base')))
```

Comment: thank you already try it and return an empty queryset: <QuerySet []>